# Counting how much time object referenced in code at compile time

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming

Is is possible to make something like this:

```
class Tag1;
class Tag2;

template <typename Tag>
void foo(){}    

void bar()
{
    //here I nee to know how many times I have referenced foo<Tag1> and foo<Tag2>

    //code chunk
    //...

    foo<Tag1>();

    //another code chunk

    foo<Tag2>();

    //much more of code and calls of foo
    ...
}
```

I need to make some progress bar on huge calculations.

p.s. I need to know it at compile time. Foo is not required to be function, it can be object but not a macro.

Comment: do you need that progress bar during compile time? where do you want to use the number of invokations of `foo<Tag1>()`, `foo<Tag2>()`, ... ?

Comment: I need to know this at compile time, before bar executed. This is need to display how much work still need to be done.

Comment: so do you want to parse the compiler output to track the progress of compilation?

Comment: No, I need to know how many times foo called in bar before bar executed to use this value at bar execution. Not paying attention to loops and other. Basically I need to know how many time foo<Tag> referenced in code, like when in IDE when I looking for references.

Comment: Can you use preprocessor macros?

Comment: Yes. Macros preprocessor is acceptable.

Comment: Do you need to count each tag separately?

Comment: Yes, but foo is not required t be a function, It can be functor object.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to count **each tag separately** then you simply create a static variable and increment it:

```
template <typename Tag>
void foo() {
    static int x = 0;
    ++x;
    // ...
}
```

Comment: How does this count each variable separately if the counter is static?

Comment: The compiler generates a seperate function for each type you pass as a template parameter.

Comment: How would you access the counters?

Comment: This is good to get count of calls at runtime, but how to get count references to function at compile time?

Answer (score 0):

We can use typeid and a map to keep track of type of objects created.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <typeinfo>
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Tag1{};
class Tag2{};

map<string, int> typeCountMap;

void getTypeCount(const string& tagname)
{
    map<string, int>::iterator itr = typeCountMap.find(tagname);

    if(itr != typeCountMap.end())
        typeCountMap[tagname] += 1;
    else
        typeCountMap[tagname] = 1;
}

template <typename Tag>
void foo(){
    getTypeCount(typeid(Tag).name());


}    

void bar()
{
    //here I nee to know how many times I have referenced foo<Tag1> and foo<Tag2>

    //code chunk
    //...

    foo<Tag1>();

    //another code chunk

    foo<Tag2>();

    //much more of code and calls of foo
    //...
}

void print(const pair<std::string, int>& entry)
{

    cout<<"type ["<<entry.first<<"] value ["<<entry.second<<"]"<<endl;
}

int main()
{
    bar();
    bar();
    bar();
    foo<Tag2>();

    for_each(typeCountMap.begin(), typeCountMap.end(), print);   
   return 0;
}


/*
output
type [4Tag1] value [3]                                                                                                                                          
type [4Tag2] value [4]
*/
```